# undefined reference in qt

Tags: c++, c, qt

In qt `MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked();`

If i want to call the function from another .c file, I have added the .c and .h files, and #include it.

But compile still show fail, it shows:

```
 undefined reference to `Load_bmp(char const*, int*, int*, int*)
```

How could i solve this issue, thanks.
Here is my code :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6RzrpHF18PGd3UtWmEzdTQyLUk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Put the code in the question. You probably just need `extern`.

Comment: I have added the extern but no use :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[qt](/questions/tagged/qt) is [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) so uses `cpp` extension files.

Fastest way, for your case, is to rename your `bmp.c` file to `bmp.cpp` and it will magically build.

Another way, ***that must be used***, is to change the interface to specify [c](/questions/tagged/c) linkage for the [c](/questions/tagged/c) project file, so:

```
#ifndef _BMP_H_
#define _BMP_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
    #endif

        unsigned char* Load_bmp(const char *fname_s, int *Height, int *Width, int *Depth);
        int Save_bmp_8bit(const char *fname_t, unsigned char *image_s, int height, int width);
        int Save_bmp_24bit(const char *fname_t, unsigned char *image_s, int height, int width);
        unsigned char * T8bitTo24bit(unsigned char *ima, size_t Height, size_t Width);
        unsigned char * T24bitTo8bit(unsigned char *ima, size_t Height, size_t Width);

    #ifdef __cplusplus
    }
    #endif
#endif
```